# AMP and code blocks

Tags: amp-html

I have a web about programming and it has some articles with code blocks. Now Google Webmaster tools reports me that I have some issues with my AMP implementation.

I have searched a bit and I think that the problem is the usage of code blocks like this:

```
<pre lang="c">
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
...
</pre>
```

AMP tools analyze this code and report me some issues, for example:

> The tag "stdio.h" isn't allowed
>
> The tag "stdlib.h" isn't allowed

I have read the AMP documentation and I haven't found any solution, so do you know how to fix it?

PD: Post the code as image isn't a valid solution for mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape '<' and '>' in your source code

```
<pre lang="c">
#include &lt;stdlib.h&gt;
#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;
#include &lt;gmp.h&gt;
...
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you are using PHP, the function [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php) scapes all special characters to avoid issues.

The required translations are (&,",',<,>)